# Display wordpress posts in day order, starting at current day?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically, I'm using a theme that allows me to show night club flyers as posts on the homepage. I simply create a post, add it to pre-defined category and it will show on the homepage as a flyer and auto-paginate etc.

What I want to be able to do it be able to show "Wednesdays" flyer if the currentday=wednesday and the pagination order to match, so next becomes Thursday > Fri > Sat > Sun > Mon etc etc

Can anyone give me ideas or maybe even a plugin link (I've yet to find one to match my needs)

Many thanks

Comment: This is the base theme http://themeforest.net/item/nocturnal-premier-audio-wp-theme-/621573

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your question is a bit too broad to answer in one time.

I'd start by adding a custom field (eg. activity_date) for the date and (preferably) saving it as a unix timestamp in the database (see WP docs for creating custom fields or metadata)

In your templates you could use a custom query such as

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'activity_date' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = " . $date . "
";

$posts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

As for the pagination, that's yet another story...

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply... sorry if I was too broad, 
Basically, I have 7 flyers (posts)... One for each day of the week, Each night we run is branded and has it's own flyer given out.

For example:

Mondays - Fuzzy Logic
Tuesdays - Student Night
...
...
Friday - Switch
...
Sun - Students

... What I want to do is (pseudocode)...

Select case (currentday()) {case:monday, order m,t,w,t,f,s,s;case:tuesday, order t,w,t,f,s,s,m;case:wednesday, order w,t,f,s,s,m,t; ...} and so on